# Installing Chronix

Tags: java, hadoop, github, jenkins, solr

I'm trying to install Chronix on my hadoop cluster(Raspbian) (http://chronix.io/) so i followed the tutorial (in Quickstart) but when i have to `$ java -jar chronix-timeseries-exploration-0.2.jar`
I got `ERROR:

> Could not find or load main Class de.qaware.chronix.examples.exploration.ui.MainRunner`

So I've read lots of things about this, how to change classpath , ... but the thing is that opposite to all of the people who were asking questions, I don't know where the file is if not in the folder : /home/hduser/chronixShowcase so I don't know where to set the PATH I tried with path at:

- /home,
- /home/user
- /home/user/chronixShowcase
- /chronixShowcase/chronix-solr-6.0.1/
- /chronixShowcase/chronix-solr-6.0.1/bin

with `CLASSPATH=path export CLASSPATH`
It may have to be downloaded but this file is not on Github (only this kind: chronix-importer/release/data/qaware-jenkins/20160226/jenkins_jenkins-jolokia_jenkins-jmx_qaware-jenkins_2016.02.27_00.00.00.csv.gz)

Do you have any suggestion to find the main class or export the right PATH or if it comes from elsewhere? I would be really happy if you could help me!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [quickstart](http://chronix.io/#quickstart) it looks like you download it from GitHub

```
wget https://github.com/ChronixDB/chronix.examples/releases/download/0.2/chronix-timeseries-exploration-0.2.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

From:    https://github.com/ChronixDB/chronix.examples/blob/master/chronix-timeseries-exploration/README.md

JavaFX is not included in OpenJDK on Linux. As a result the following error occurs when starting the application with OpenJDK.

**Solution**

Use Oracle JDK that includes JavaFX
Install the missing JavaFX package for OpenJDK, e.g for Ubuntu:
Try:

> sudo apt-get install openjfx